# Update ASP.NET page after Excel Export

Tags: asp.net, excel, response

I'm using Response.Write, Response.End to export to Excel/Word/csv. Is there a way to do this and also be able to change text on the page at the same time? For example, I have a controls within an UpdatePanel which I want to make visible/invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Update your page via the AJAX action and, in the process, write out some javascript that calls a separate page/handler that does the actual export.

```
 if (exporting)
 {
     string cacheID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     Session[cacheID] = ...data or query to export...
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,
             Page.GetType(),
             cacheid,
             "window.location = '/download.ashx?cacheid=" + cacheID + "';",
             True);
 }
```

Comment: @SLaks - depends on where your sessions are stored.  I'd assume in a clustered or load-balanced environment you'd be storing the sessions in the database.  In that case, though, I'd probably store the means to generate the query rather than the results of the query.